# How to change the value of select2 option onload?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 like this:

```
  $("#select2").select2({
    tags: true,
    placeholder: "選択して下さい",
    data: select2_data,
  });
```

The value of data is:

```
["data1", "data2", "data3"]
```

giving my option like this:

```
<option value="data1" data-select2-id="68">data1</option>
<option value="data2" data-select2-id="69">data2</option>
<option value="data3" data-select2-id="70">data3</option>
```

How do I change the value from data1 to 1, data2 to 2 and so on?

Comment: Are you trying to change the `value=` eg `<option value="data1"` to `<option value="1"`?

Answer (score 0):

To convert from:

```
<option value="data1">data1</option>
```

to

```
<option value="1">data1</option>
```

when loading into select2, you can transform the source array into an object array in the [format that select2 expects](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats)

```
[ { id: 1, text: "data1" }, { id: 2, text: "data2" } ...
```

Giving:

```js
var data = ["data1", "data2", "data3"];

// Transform array into { id, text }
var select2data = $.map(data, function(obj) {
  return {
    id: obj.substr(4),
    text: obj
  };
});
//console.log(select2data)

// Initalise select2 with updated data
$('#select2').select2({
  tags: true,
  placeholder: "選択して下さい",
  data: select2data,
});


// Testing example to see selected output
$('#select2').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  var data = e.params.data;
  console.log(data.id, data.text);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="select2"></select>
```